# SSLContext not using certificate from the JVM TrustStore

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-client-authentication

I need to send a request to a server that uses TLS Client Authentication. For that, I created a PKCS12 file with my certificate and private key and set it in the SSLContext as a KeyManager.

```
KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
keystoreInputStream = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/PC/Desktop/certprivate.p12");
keystore.load(keystoreInputStream, "password".toCharArray());

KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
kmf.init(keystore, "password".toCharArray());

SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.3");
sc.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), null, null);
```

I also used keytool to add the certificate from the server in the `cacerts` store and while that didn't work, I used InstallCerts to download I guess all of the intermediary certificates and installed thoses in cacerts. The problem I'm getting now is `400 No required SSL certificate was sent`.

I'm not sure why this shows up, when from my understanding, if the `TrustManager` is set to null, it will use the default TrustManager which in this case is:

```
String certificatesTrustStorePath = "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-15.0.2/lib/security/cacerts";
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", certificatesTrustStorePath);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "changeit");
```

EDIT: I don't get why the request is failing as the TLS handshake has been completed. Otherwise I would have gotten some other error/exception.

Answer (score 0):

Add -Djavax.net.debug=all in your java startup command line, you will have more informations.
After you could diagnose your issue.
JC

Answer (score 0):

I might be late with a potential answer. But I faced same issue and as per my experience due to some issue while setting up the SSLContext, provided trustStores and keyStores are not picked up in Java 11 specifically for me. So I had to set them up using JVM arguments. But setting trustStore and keyStore is not enough, please set up the passwords too for both of them. This worked for me. Additionally I also set up the TLS protocol to TLSv1.2. I hope this helps.